# Is there always isomorphism between two sets that have the same cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is there always isomorphism between two sets that has the same cardinality ?

We only know that the two sets have the same cardinality. I tried to find a counter example but couldn't.

Comment: What kind of isomorphism?

Comment: The relation '$X$ has the same cardinality of $Y$' is usually defined to mean 'there exists a bijection $X \cong Y$'. When you say isomorphism do you mean bijection? Because if so then you'll be searching for a long time for a counterexample!

Comment: @AymanHourieh any or all of them I guess ?

Comment: @GinKin: Unless you endow your sets with additional structure, the only notion of isomorphism that makes sense is bijection... in which case, it's simply the definition of 'having the same cardinality'. If you give your sets additional structure then it's usually false, e.g. there are non-isomorphic groups of cardinality $6$ (dihedral $\not \cong$ cyclic).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By definition there is always a *bijection* between two sets of the same cardinality, Otherwise they wouldn't have the same cardinality.

However, calling it an "isomorphism" suggests that you're looking for a bijection that *preserves some kind of additional structure*, and until you tell us *which* kind of additional structure you want preserved, the question can't really be answered.

For most practically occurring cases, I think the answer will be "no, there exist non-isomorphic such-and-suches with the same cardinality". But there are pathological corner cases where this is not the case, for example if we consider isomorphisms between standard models of the pure predicate calculus with equality over the empty language.

Or, somewhat less trivially: For any finite field $K$, if two *vector spaces over $K$* have the same cardinality, then they're isomorphic as $K$-vector spaces.

Comment: Can we generalize for any preserving structure at all ?

Comment: @GinKin: "Structure" is an informal concept, so you cannot quantify over all kinds of structure. But as in my last sentence, you can view any set as a model of the pure predicate calculus with equality over the empty language, and every bijection between sets will then (boringly) be an isomorphism between such models.

Comment: "pure predicate calculus with equality over the empty language" I have no idea what this means but I believe you. Thanks.

Comment: @GinKin - as Henning says, the concept of *isomorphism* is "meaningful" between *structures* i.e. set+operation (e.g.natural numbers with addition) or set+relation (e.g.a poset). If you have only two sets of equal cardinality (without opeartions or relations) the concept of *isomorphism* reduces to a plain bijection between the two sets. Henning suggest to consider at least the "basic" relation of equality (between the elements of the sets); in this way you have a "basic" relation and you will ask to the bijection $\phi$ that it preserves equality (i.e. if $a=b$, then $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$).