# Are all sets in Set, with the same cardinality, isomorphic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

It is said, that all singleton sets are isomorphic(and terminal objects).

I wonder if this is true for any cardinality in the category of sets.

For example, are all two element sets isomorphic in the catergory of sets?

If not, why does this property only hold for singleton sets?

Comment: What does it mean for two sets to have the same cardinality? What does it mean for two sets to be isomorphic in Set?

Comment: Yes, of course it is true. Answering the questions by Gae. S gives you a proof.

Comment: Is this site for asking for an answer, or receiving counter questions? Nevermind if my question was too dumb...

Comment: In mathematics you should try to think yourself to really understand these things. Gae's questions are hints to help you that immediately give you the entire proof.

Comment: @QiZhu: I know, but still this site emphasis is about answers. This sort of conversation with counter questions is more suited to a chat room, don't you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, two sets $A,B$ have the same cardinality if they are bijective to each other, i.e. there exist mutually inverse functions $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to A$. This is precisely the definition of an isomorphism in $\mathbf{Set}$.

Singletons then of course turn out to be a special case. It seems however that you are reading a passage about terminal objects of which singletons form an example in $\mathbf{Set}$. Since all terminal objects are canonically isomorphic (due to universal property nonsense), the isomorphism immediately follows here.

Comment: Thx, I got confused by this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710879/is-there-always-isomorphism-between-two-sets-that-have-the-same-cardinality and the answers were not so clear to me